# Simultaneous access to Database in Web application

Tags: java, database, glassfish, connection-pooling

How can I know the average or exact number of users accessing database simultaneously in my Java EE web enterprise application? I would like to see if the "Connection pool setting" I set in the Glassfish application server is suitable for my web application or not. I need to correctly set the maximun number of connection in Connection Pool setting in Application Server. Recently, my application ran out of connections and threw exceptions when the client request for DB expires.

Comment: Are you sure you are closing the connections properly after using them?

Comment: In web application, yes I'm closing connections & statements. However, sometime a few people directly access the DB and I worry that they sometimes forget to close them properly. In DB conf file, I see the max number of connection is 100. Please note, there are several users of this web application & in connection pool the no. of max connection set to 4 only. So I increased it for the moment. I would like to know if there is some way to monitor the average no. of requests using db connection sumultaneously.

Comment: Are you sure that you need a database connection for each user?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways.

One and easiest would be take help from your DBAs - they can tell you exactly how many connections are active from your webserver or the user id for connection pool at a given time.

If you want some excitement, you will have to JMX management extensions provided by glassfish. Listing 6 on [this page](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kalali/archive/2010/04/06/manage-administrate-and-monitor-glassfish-v3-java-code-using-amx-jmx) - gives an example as to how to write a JMS based snippet to monitor a connection pool.

Finally, you must make sure that all connections are closed explicitly by a `connection.close();` type of call in your application. In some cases, you need to close ResultSet as well.
Next is throttling your http thread pool to avoid too many concurrent access if your db connections are taking longer to close.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, link you referred is quite interesting. However you mentioned "In some cases, you need to close RecordSets as well" and I also listened same thing from lot of experts, I would like to know in which cases its important to close resultset explicitly. They should be closed with statements. Can you please let me know.

Comment: Hi - ideally, a `ResultSet` would close out when the statement object is closed. Some driver vendors don't implement that specification properly. So safe to close both. No harm in it. This is applicable when you leave your statement opened for some other processing.